# LARAVEL update error Call to a member function update() on null

Tags: sql-update, laravel-8

```
        $update = TicketDetails::find($ticket_id)
        ->update([
            'redirected' => '1',
            'department_id' => $department_id
        ]);
```

Doesn't work. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem. The `$ticket_id` variable was the null.